# AWS Allow traffic to EC2 only from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have one single page app hosted at S3 bucket. It uses app API located at EC2 instance behind Network Load Balancer. Because of this specific load balancer constraints I can't use SG and control traffic flow to EC2 instance. The ideal scenario supposed to be:

1. S3 call NLB
2. NLB call API on EC2
3. Traffic to EC2 instance is limited only from NLB, all other is blocked,

Unfortunately now to sustain communication between S3 and EC2 I need to open specific port and allow traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 which is my nightmare.
Maybe there is anyone knows any solution which would be good in my case. Maybe there is any way to limit traffic from S3 service?

Comment: You seem to be a fundamental misconception about something in your setup.  *"1. S3 call NLB"* is impossible.  S3 only stores content; it never contacts any server for any reason.  It sounds like you are wanting to restrict access to EC2 for only *browsers* who are *displaying* your app, which happens to be stored in a bucket and is making connections from the browser to your server... but this is very different than saying S3 is connecting to your server.  It isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the security group on your Amazon EC2 instance can be configured to only accept traffic from the NLB.

From [Register Targets with Your Target Group - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html#target-security-groups):

> Network Load Balancers do not have associated security groups. Therefore, the security groups for your targets must use IP addresses to allow traffic from the load balancer.
>
> ...you can grant access to the private IP addresses used by the load balancer nodes. There is one IP address per load balancer subnet.

However, anyone can call the Network Load Balancer, and therefore get to the EC2 instance(s).

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 is an object storage service. If your application is served by S3, it means S3 serves HTML, CSS and JavaScript content to your customer’s browsers. The JavaScript is executed on the client side, not on S3. So it is not possible to restrict EC2 API access from S3.

I would suggest to use Amazon Cognito to authenticate your customers and restrict API access to authenticated customers.